# Time-Distance chart using AFreeChart

Tags: android, jfreechart

I want to create a time-distance chart that will show the position (on the x axis) at a certain time (on the y axis). I successfully integrated the library in my project and I rendered an empty chart. However, I'm not sure what kind of chart to use a Line Chart, a XY Line Chart or a Time Series Chart and I don't know how should I provide the data (the position at a certain time e.g. at second 5 the distance is 10 meters) for the chart to be drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this thread for reference.

http://www.android-graphview.org/

Comment: Thank you! This library was useful.